# Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined in Amplify UI in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amplifyjs

I installed Amplify Pagination to beautify my project, however, things got weird after I pasted code in my project, the console always shows

Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/pagination

I then created a default React project but the result remains the same.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { AmplifyProvider } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'; // default theme

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AmplifyProvider>
      <App />
    </AmplifyProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
import { Pagination } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Pagination
      currentPage={1}
      totalPages={10}
      siblingCount={1}
      onChange={()=>this.onChange()}
      onNext={()=>this.onNext()}
      onPrevious={()=>this.onPrevious()}
    />

      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the behavior of `this` in arrow functions ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). Notice the functions you pass as the event handler props vs those in the example in the docs you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" is undefined because you are not in a class component

```
function App() {
    const onChange = () => { do something }
    const onNext = () => { do something }
    const onPrevious = () => { do something }
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Pagination
          currentPage={1}
          totalPages={10}
          siblingCount={1}
          onChange={onChange}
          onNext={onNext}
          onPrevious={onPrevious}
        />
    
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```